# How do I wrap all text nodes with <p> in a div that also may contain other <p> tags and tags such as <strong> using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the below example html:

```
<div>
Wrap this text with p which also includes <strong>this</strong> and also <a href="">this</a>.
<h1>Heading 1</h1>
<p>Some other text</p>
Wrap this text with p which also includes <strong>this</strong> and also <a href="">this</a>.
</div>
```

the desired result using jQuery:

```
<div>
<p>Wrap this text with p which also includes <strong>this</strong> and also <a href="">this</a>.</p>
<h1>Heading 1</h1>
<p>Some other text</p>
<p>Wrap this text with p which also includes <strong>this</strong> and also <a href="">this</a>.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: So why are `span` and `a` included into `p`, but `h1` is not? What tags should be wrapped what should be skipped?

Comment: If I were to hazard a guess, it's because `strong` and `a` are phrasing content while `h1` is flow content, and `p` cannot contain flow content - you *couldn't* wrap an `h1` in a `p` even if you tried.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qLxcexd5/2/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qLxcexd5/3/

Answer (score 2):

I think you could iterate over the contents of the div and create a group of items to be wrapped as given below

```
var $group = $();

$('div').contents().each(function () {
    if (this.nodeType == 3 || !$(this).is(':header, div, p')) {
        if (this.nodeType != 3 || this.nodeValue.trim()) {
            $group = $group.add(this);
        }
    } else {
        $group.wrapAll('<p />')
        $group = $()
    }
});
$group.wrapAll('<p />')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qLxcexd5/)